# Formatting MDX queries in either Visual Studio or SSMS

Tags: visual-studio, ssms, ssas, mdx, olap

Is there a way to auto-format an MDX queries? For example, the produced query is always one line:

[image]

I wouldn't expect the "Format SQL" button to work on MDX, but I'm wondering if there is any button, tool, or plugin that auto-formats the MDX queries so it's more like a formatted, readable, query and not just a long line of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there is a format option in either Visual Studio or SSMS. The only thing that comes to my mind is [MDX Studio](https://www.sqlbi.com/tools/mdx-studio/) developed by Mosha Pasumansky:

You have format option:

[image]